# magento 2 swatches are not displaying on product list page

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.3.2 color swatches are not displaying on product list page.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below solution

1.- Login to **admin panel**

2.- Go To **Stores** (left menu)

3.- Product (under attribute section)

4.- Select the attribute you want to edit, for example color,size etc

5.- Storefront Properties (in the Attribute Information menu on the left)

6.- Look for Used in product listing option and set it to **YES**

Comment: Yes I tried Thanks.. And it worked only for some of the swatch attribute.

Comment: @poornima, Can you please up vote my answer if it's help you any way